# BeautifulSoup returns spaced text after parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a local html document. However, when I parse it with beautiful soup it returns the html in an ugly (shown in pic below) formatting which is unparsable.

[image]

The simple code I used is:

```
path = 'alerts/myfile.htm'
file = open(os.path.abspath(path))
parser = BeautifulSoup(file,'html.parser')
file.close()
```

This thing is driving me crazy. Have you ever had the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: can you provide the html file?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the original file is in UTF-16.

For whichever reason, `BeautifulSoup(..., from_encoding='utf-16le')` doesn't understand this situation, but you can work around this by reading and decoding the file manually before passing it to BS.

See below for a transcript where I create a HTML file that's UTF-16LE, dump its contents, try to pass it directly into BS4 and finally use the workaround described above.

```
$ echo '<html><div>hello</div></html>' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le > y.html
$ file y.html
$ xxd y.html
00000000: 3c00 6800 7400 6d00 6c00 3e00 3c00 6400  <.h.t.m.l.>.<.d.
00000010: 6900 7600 3e00 6800 6500 6c00 6c00 6f00  i.v.>.h.e.l.l.o.
00000020: 3c00 2f00 6400 6900 7600 3e00 3c00 2f00  <./.d.i.v.>.<./.
00000030: 6800 7400 6d00 6c00 3e00 0a00            h.t.m.l.>...
$ python
>>> import bs4
>>> s = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('y.html'))
&lt;html&gt;&lt;div&gt;hello&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
>>> s = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('y.html'), from_encoding='utf-16le')
&lt;html&gt;&lt;div&gt;hello&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
>>> s = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('y.html'), 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-16le')
&lt;html&gt;&lt;div&gt;hello&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
>>> d = open('y.html', 'rb').read().decode('utf-16le')
>>> d
'<html><div>hello</div></html>\n'
>>> s = bs4.BeautifulSoup(d)
>>> s
<html><div>hello</div></html>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me a problem regarding the source file encoding.

When loading the document, BeautifulSoup converts it in UTF-8, using a sub-library called [Unicode Dammit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit).

It could be that your file has been saved with a different encoding and some kind of error happened in the conversion.

Since I don't have your html at hand I can suggest you to investigate whether your file is ASCII or Unicode or any other encoding, and then parse the file with:

```
encoding = <your encoding here> (example "iso-8859-8")
parser = BeautifulSoup(file,'html.parser', from_encoding=encoding)
```

Other encoding options can be found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings)

Regards

**UPDATE**

Try also:

```
parser = BeautifulSoup(file,'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it: My file was in UCL-2 encoding. What I did was:

```
 path = 'alerts/myfile.htm'
file = open(os.path.abspath(path),'rb')
parser = BeautifulSoup(file.read().decode('utf-8'),'html.parser')
file.close()
parser.find('table', attrs = {'class':'MsoNormalTable'})
```

Here now the output:

[image]